# Sqlite Request syntax Android

Tags: android, sqlite

here is my request

```
query = ("UPDATE " + "DELIVERY_SLIP"
                        + " SET DATELASTCHECK_SI = " + "'" + DATELASTCHECK_SI
                        + "'" + " and " + "BOOL_SI = " + BOOL_SI + " WHERE "
                        + "DELIVERY_SLIP.TITLE_SI" + " = " + "'"
                        + currentDS.TITLE_SI + "'");
```

On debugger I can see that

```
UPDATE DELIVERY_SLIP SET DATELASTCHECK_SI = '2/12/1995' and BOOL_SI = 1 WHERE DELIVERY_SLIP.TITLE_SI = 'null.jpg'
```

null.jpg exist , it's just the name ,

2/12/1995 is a date pass on parameters of the function, = 1 ; is an int pass on parameters too.

I made an error on selection table maybe but i don't know where ?

THE SOLUTION :

```
ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
                    initialValues.put("_id", currentDS.getID());
                    initialValues.put("TITLE_SI", currentDS.getTitle());
                    initialValues.put("BOOL_SI", BOOL_SI);
                    initialValues.put("DATELASTCHECK_SI", DATELASTCHECK_SI);

                    db.update("DELIVERY_SLIP", initialValues, "_id" + " = ?",
                            new String[] { String.valueOf(currentDS._id) });
```

Comment: So, what is the problem?

Comment: Sorry for this beginner question , i found the solution but i don't know why this request didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [SQLiteDatabase.update](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update(java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) method for this request.

It would looks like this one for your case:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("DATELASTCHECK_SI", DATELASTCHECK_SI);
values.put("BOOL_SI", BOOL_SI);
db.update("DELIVERY_SLIP", values, "TITLE_SI=?", new String[]{String.valueOf( currentDS.TITLE_SI) });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this, put your arguments and table and condtions

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("SMS", newSmsNumber);
cv.put("Voice", newVoiceNumber);
db.update("[table name]", cv, "ID=?", new String[]{Integer.toString(id)});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the UPDATE statement, multiple columns to be set must be separated not with AND but with commas.

`SET DATELASTCHECK_SI = '2/12/1995' and BOOL_SI = 1` is interpreted as setting the single column `DATELASTCHECK_SI` to the value of the expression `'2/12/1995' and BOOL_SI = 1`, in which AND is a boolean operator; the final value of this expression is either 0 or 1.

Replace the `AND` with a comma, or better use a helper function like `update` that formats the statement and the values for you.